# What receptive field do we have after stacking $n \times n$ CONV layers with kernel size $k \times k$?

Tags: self-study, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, convolution

What **receptive field** do we have after stacking $n \times n$ convolutional layers with kernel size $k \times k$ and stride $1$? Layers numeration starts with $1$. The resulting receptive field will be a square.

---

The intuition I got from Coursera Discussion Forums is that the formula should be something like $k+2 \times n-2 = k + 2 \times (n-1)$.

For $k=3$ it gives $2 \times n + 1$ as well as the [slide](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1e63W0AgTWcKkmgaJEqa5DAPC0nEmlqmR) says, but this is right only for $k=3$ and for $k= 4\ (5, 6,\ etc.)$, the coefficient $2$ should increase too.

I didn't get the idea behind this. Could someone explain, please?

Comment: This manual could help you: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.07285.pdf

Comment: Thanks, @JanKukacka. I got the correct answer. It is: $n\times(k-1)+1\ X\ n\times(k-1)+1$

Comment: @Joe. Can you please explain how you got this formula because what I understood that the receptive field after $N$ convolutions will be $
2N+1\times 2N+1
$? Do you got the formula from manual Jan posted? If yes, can you please cite the page number?

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider only odd k (3, 5, 7...), in which case the kernel will have a center cell.

On each next layer, we add extra `(k-1)/2` border to the opposite edges of the field, which adds `(k-1)` cells to each side of the field.

This gives us  `1 + n * (k - 1)`.

*The question is about the simplest case (the stride is 1 and the kernel is dense). Formulas for more complex cases (stride > 1 and even-sided kernels) can be found in [this paper](https://distill.pub/2019/computing-receptive-fields/).*

Comment: This would be correct for a 1D-CNN, but the question is asking about 2D-CNNs.

Comment: This will even work for 3D-CNN =)

Comment: See Joe's comment on the question for the extension of your answer to the 2D case.

Comment: There is no 2D case, actually. We calculate each dimension independently. And the field does not have to be a square (it could be 3×5 cells, for example).